# can I make file input and add value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

can I make file input and add value in HTML like below?
Because it seems not working.

```
  const videoInput = document.createElement("input");
  videoInput.type = "file";
  videoInput.value = videoFile;
  RecordForm.appendChild(videoInput);
```

from this i guess it should make this *** line added.
But it doesn't work.

**pug file**

```
    form#RecordForm(method="POST")
        input#DateInput(type="date" name="date")
        label(for="title") Title:
        input#TitleInput(type="text" name="title")
        input(type="file" value=videoFile) ***
```

Comment: no - a file input requires a user to select a file - imagine the security risks your code would pose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create file input with selected file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236724/is-it-possible-to-create-file-input-with-selected-file)

Comment: @Bravo ok i understand. so it should not work. thanks.

Comment: I may have been hasty, perhaps in some odd environments it's possible, certainly NOT in a browser though

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
videoInput.value = videoFile;
```

Change it to

```
videoInput.files.file[0] = videoFile;
```

Since it an input type file

Comment: for me it seems not working T_T I guess as Bravo said above, it doens't work this way for security problem..?